# How to do jquery browser tab active after 2 minute?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my website that if a user login to my website and he will move to another tab into browser so after 2 minute the website the tab going to be active that tab where my website is open.........

Comment: what have you tried?you cant just say `please solve my query` in SO.you must try something and have suggestion from SO people

Comment: do you have answer for my question @peter